# How to make a service in this case?

Tags: android, service, sip

So i have a class that listens to incoming calls, i want to make a service to all my app to receive calls even when i'm not in the application's UI.
How to trigger this class(broadcast receiver). I used "sendBroadcast" and have a FC.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(context, IncomingCallReceiver.class));
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: m not sure but i think broadcast receiver receives the events even your app is closed...

Comment: @Farhan: no, i verified it right now and it's not working. Any idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: yes broadcast receiver receive event even if you have closed your application.

Comment: @Sujit: i re-verified it and i'm not receiving calls when closing the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I would use the following approach:

- Create `Service` and start it from your `Activity` (you mentioned that you have several applications, so starting first of them may also start the Service).
- Make sure that Service does not work forever, so stop the service when you do not need it any more (last of your applications is finished). Service may terminate self even without Activity by calling `stopSelf()`. Please note that also System may terminate your Service and prevent it from working forever.
- Make private class within Service that extends BroadcastReceiver and register it for the Intents you want to monitor using Service function `registerReceiver()`.
- Once you receive wanted Intent, you can call some Service function from within BroadcastReceiver `onReceive()`. For example, you may sendBroadcast() using some custom Intent that is recognized by your applications.
- When Service is stopped make sure that you un-register the BroadcastReceiver extension using Service function `unregisterReceiver()`.

**UPDATE:**

- [Service building guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html)
- SDK example that illustrates BroadcastReceiver extension usage within Activity. All important related to register/unregister is the same if you do that within Service: android-sdk-windows\samples\android-8\Home\src\com\example\android\home\Home.java
- [Start Activity from Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service)
- [Handle the case of Activity already running in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887627/the-meaning-of-intent-flags-in-android)

Comment: Have you please a guide link that talks about this steps? Thank you.

Comment: @androniennn - I will update my answer tommorow morning with some useful links/examples.