# The meaning of FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

In intent I can set such flag as `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`. Can somebody explain me its meaning, cause I just don't get it? =)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[The tasks page says for single top:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

> If an instance of the activity already exists at the top of the current task, the system routes the intent to that instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance of the activity. The activity can be instantiated multiple times, each instance can belong to different tasks, and one task can have multiple instances (but only if the the activity at the top of the back stack is not an existing instance of the activity).
>
> For example, suppose a task's back
>   stack consists of root activity A with
>   activities B, C, and D on top (the
>   stack is A-B-C-D; D is on top). An
>   intent arrives for an activity of type
>   D. If D has the default "standard"
>   launch mode, a new instance of the
>   class is launched and the stack
>   becomes A-B-C-D-D. However, if D's
>   launch mode is "singleTop", the
>   existing instance of D is deliverd the
>   intent through onNewIntent(), because
>   it's at the top of the stack—the stack
>   remains A-B-C-D. However, if an intent
>   arrives for an activity of type B,
>   then a new instance of B is added to
>   the stack, even if its launch mode is
>   "singleTop".

Answer (score 0):

[Javadoc says:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)

```
If set, the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of 
the history stack.
```