# Android, start activity from service?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

Trying to start activity from service started at BOOT, but log shows how application dies (don't know why exactly) and restarts and tries again and again..

I've tried differents ways of starting activity, like

```
Intent newUserForm = new Intent(_context, NewUserForm.class);
newUserForm.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
_context.startActivity(newUserForm);
```

Why is my app dying (and restarting) and I'm not able to start activity from service?
Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: Perhaps you could post the log showing how your application dies?

Comment: ..: INFO/ActivityManager(72): Start proc Test_1.Android for service Test_1.Android/.BOOTService: pid=526 uid=10032 gids={3003}  
..: WARN/ActivityManager(72): Timeout executing service: ServiceRecord{43a51c08 Test_1.Android/. BOOTService }  
..: INFO/Process(72): Sending signal. PID: 526 SIG: 9  
..: INFO/ActivityManager(72): Process Test_1.Android (pid 526) has died.  
..: WARN/ActivityManager(72): Scheduling restart of crashed service Test_1.Android/. BOOTService in 20000ms

Comment: service itself: new Intent(this, NewUserForm.class); || getApplicationContext()

Comment: solved, not really understanded :), probably a context theme...

To solve problem, I started activity from BroadcastReceiver launched on BOOT ...

`public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Intent newUserForm = new Intent(context, NewUserForm.class);
            newUserForm.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
            context.startActivity(newUserForm);

}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [android start activity from service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service)

Answer (score 1):

Broadcast one Intent from service and make sure you'll receive that Intent from your application side (broadcast receiver).

Answer (score 0):

Set up a broadcast receiver, and start the service from there.