# How can I get the application context from an Android Service?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service, android-activity

I have an Android service that is running and listening for microphone input. I want it to launch an activity when a certain criteria is met. In order to create an Intent I need the application context. How can I get it?

```
Intent i = new Intent(ctx, SONR.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
ctx.startActivity(i);
```

The above line does not start my activity.

**Here is my constructor**

```
public SONRClient(Context c, AudioRecord ar, int buffsize, final AudioManager am) {
    theAudioManager = am;
    theaudiorecord = ar;
    bufferSize = buffsize;
    ctx = c;
    CLIENT_ON = true;
}
```

**Here is my onCreate**

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    try {
        // LogFile.MakeLog("\n\nSONRClient CREATED");
        clientStopReceiver = new StopReceiver();
        ctx.registerReceiver(clientStopReceiver, 
            new IntentFilter(SONR.DISCONNECT_ACTION));
        myByteReceiver = new SONRByteReceiver();
        theListener = new MicSerialListener(
            theaudiorecord, bufferSize, myByteReceiver);
        theApplication = getApplication();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ErrorReporter.getInstance().handleException(e);
    }
}
```

**There is myByteReceiver** that is listening for signals via audio input. When it finds a matching signal, I want it to launch an activity.

```
private class SONRByteReceiver implements ByteReceiver {
    private long lastplaytime = 0;
    private long lastmutetime = 0;
    private long lastskiptime = 0;
    private long lastvolutime = 0;
    private long lastbacktime = 0;

    public void receiveByte(int receivedByte) {
        try {
            theKeyEvent = -1;

            if (ismuted) {
                if (receivedByte != MUTE) {
                    volume = 0;
                    ismuted = false;
                }
            }

            switch (receivedByte) {

            case SONR_HOME:
                Log.d(TAG, "HOME");

                Intent i = new Intent(ctx, SONR.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                theApplication.startActivity(i);

                break;
            default:
                Log.d(TAG, "default");
                Log.d(TAG,"RECEIVED " + receivedByte);
                // LogFile.MakeLog("RECEIVED " + receivedByte);
                break;
            }

            if (theKeyEvent >= 0) {
                sendbroadcast();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            ErrorReporter.getInstance().handleException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the stacktrace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sonrlabs.test.sonr.SONRClient$SONRByteReceiver.receiveByte(SONRClient.java:320)
    at com.sonrlabs.test.sonr.AudioProcessor.processSample(AudioProcessor.java:145)
    at com.sonrlabs.test.sonr.AudioProcessor.run(AudioProcessor.java:58)
```

Line 320 is `theApplication.startActivity(i);`

Comment: Could you post the method you call `getApplicationContext` in?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you posted the log of the NullPointerException you are getting.

Comment: None of your code seems to assign anything to the ctx variable. Review your code to see where "ctx" is assigned a value and do some print outs around the assignment to see when and if it is ever assigned.

Comment: ctx is assigned, in my constructor. i can post that code as well

Comment: I also print out the package name from my context. And it does it fine. Problem is in startActivity. Not sure why.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of atm is that your SONR activity may not be defined in your manifest.

Comment: Can you post the code which calls the SONRClient constructor? It seems you are passing a null value into this constructor.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
ctx.getApplicationContext().startActivity(i)
```

boom.

Comment: what is ctx ?? Do you launch the instruction above from the service?

Comment: @Lisitso `ctx` is a `Context` variable

Comment: If you already have ctx as Context why get application context and then startActivity? Why not simply ctx.startActivity()?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `getApplicationContext()` inside your service to get the application context.

Try using

```
getApplication().startActivity(i);
```

[android start activity from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service)

Comment: I get a null pointer exception when I try getApplicationContext()

Comment: I updated my code. I have a reference to the context, but my activity does not show up. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How are you starting the service? Can you edit your question with more complete code from the service, such as which lifecycle methods you try to start the activity in?

Comment: Try moving `theApplication = getApplication();` to the first line of onCreate

Comment: Still get a nullpointerexception for `theApplication.startActivity(i);`

Answer (score 5):

**Every Service has its own Context, just use the that. You don't need to pass a Service an Activity's Context.**

No need for activity context in Service.

```
Intent i = new Intent(ctx, SONR.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

**Simply do as you do in Activity**

> Service and Activity both are subclasses of Context.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ctx, SONR.class);
```

to:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SONR.class);
```

Comment: Impossible, You are getting null pointer exception somewhere else. If your service is running then context cant be null.

Comment: Try to click on this line :  at com.sonrlabs.test.sonr.AudioProcessor.processSample(AudioProcessor.java:145) or line above n below that, to find whr u r getting null.

Answer (score 1):

You're assertion that you need an application context to start an activity is inaccurate. You can [start an activity from any context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29), including the service, which is a context.

Comment: I tried it using just startActivity(), I still get a nullpointerexception. Updated question with more code

Comment: Show the stack track for the null pointer. It's not because of a null service if you're using it from within that class.

Comment: The stacktrace in the question is all that is printed when I am debugging. Any ideas on how to debug further?

Answer (score 1):

**getBaseContext()** which returns context since every activity extends Context class

Answer (score 1):

You mustn't call to `getApplicationContext()` inside its public empty constructor, or it will give you a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Where in the `Service` class is a safe place to call `getApplicationContext()`?

Comment: @JJD don't call getApplicationContext(), call to getBaseContext() as Vishal Android Developer wrote.

Comment: Still the question remains in which method it is safe to be called.

Answer (score 0):

There is a not null context only after 'onCreate()' of the Service : getting the context of the service in the constructor is not a good idea (not yet any context), get it with the simple 'getApplicationContext()' in the 'onCreate' method.

Answer (score -1):

Just do this to access the Service context

```
Intent i = new Intent(Service.this, SONR.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```