# Getting the service context in a timer so I can use a toast

Tags: android, service, toast

I know I can get a service context using this in the onCreate() method in a service.
In my service, I'm using a timer to do something. And I want to produce a toast when that something is done. However, I can not access the service context in my timer in order to produce the toast.
I can access the context with this in the onCreate() method

How can I pass the context (so I can use it to create a toast) to the timer running in the service
Any ideas?

Comment: ^+1. Also have you tried using getApplicationContext() ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are questions providing answers to similar question:

[How can I get the application context from an Android Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305496/how-can-i-get-the-application-context-from-an-android-service)

[android start activity from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom app class extended from Application class. Then in onCreate init context member with own instance of MyApp. Now you can get context everywhere you want:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private static MyApp mContext;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate() {
        mContext= this;
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public static MyApp getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

Then you can get context by calling `MyApp.getContext();`

Dont forget to add atribute name=MyApp in  in manifest:

```
...
<application
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
     android:label="@string/application_name"
     android:name="MyApp">
...
```