# android startActivity from intent in service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

i try to use intent in service but when i try this :

```
Intent intent_facebook = new Intent (this,MainUploadToYoutube.class);
intent_facebook.putExtra("vid", vid);
startActivity(intent_facebook);
```

got this error on logcat :

```
Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

so i tried this from here :

[android start activity from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service)

```
Intent  intent_facebook = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainUploadToYoutube.class);
intent_facebook.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().startActivity( intent_facebook);
```

but this do nothing and i did not get error in logcat

what wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried your own code (using `this` as context), but just add the flags as the error tells you?

```
Intent intent_facebook = new Intent (this, MainUploadToYoutube.class);
intent_facebook.putExtra("vid", vid);
intent_facebook.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent_facebook);
```

Comment: work .... i add in extra intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

Answer (score 0):

this may help

in `Service` class  you get `context` and initialize with `Context` `mContext`

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,MainUploadToYoutube.class);   
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
 ((Activity)mContext).startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Context mContext = getBaseContext();
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(mContext,MainUploadToYoutube.class);   
 intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
 ((Activity)mContext).startActivity(intent2);  i try this but mcontext could not cast to activity

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. It should work. Your problem is something  else. Make sure MainUploadToYoutube activity is defined in the manifest and app may not crash once this activity is lunched.