# how to open preference activity from android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-keypad

I was making android keyboard using the same structure of the sample keyboard in SDK. I have an option button on the keyboard. I want this button to open the preference activity. Here is the code part:

```
if (primaryCode == LatinKeyboardView.KEYCODE_OPTIONS) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ImePreferences.class);
        startActivity(i);           
    }
```

The keyboard freezes when i press the option button. Anybody with a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (primaryCode == LatinKeyboardView.KEYCODE_OPTIONS) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ImePreferences.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);           
}
```

As you can see, the intent requires adding a flag which specifies new task/activity.

Comment: Actually I found the answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service .. The Keyboard is a service. Anyways Thanks.