# NullPointerException in new Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, android-service, android-notifications

I'm trying to send a message from the `Service` and I receive an error

> Error at com.spynetstation.MediaService.notif(MediaService.java:162)

which points to this line in the `Service`:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(ctx, MediaService.class);
```

**Service:**

```
public class MediaService extends Service implements OnPreparedListener,OnCompletionListener{

    static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    static NotificationManager nm;
    private static NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    static Context ctx;

    static String dataPlaying = null;
    static String soursetrack = null;
    static TimerTask repeatTask;
    static Timer t;
    Node node;
    static String filePath;
    static File file;
    String titleNotif = "Station";
    String contentNotif = "Running";

    public IBinder onBind(Intent paramIntent)  {
        return null;
    }

    public static void initMP(String urlStream){
        try {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(urlStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        Log.d("MediaService", "prepareAsync");
    }

    public static void startMP(){
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
                Log.d("MediaService", "start");
                MainActivity.visible();
                if (MainActivity.track) {} else {doRepeatTask();}
            }
        });   
    }

    public static void stopMP() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.stop(); 
                Log.d("MediaService", "stop");
                if (MainActivity.track) {} else {stopRepeatTask();}
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void releaseMP() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.release();
                Log.d("MediaService", "release"); 
                mediaPlayer = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.d("MediaService", "onCompletion"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.d("MediaService", "onPrepareed");
    }

    public void onCreate()  {
        super.onCreate();
        // tried the following ctx=getBaseContext(); did not help
        ctx = getApplicationContext();
        this.nm = ((NotificationManager)getSystemService("notification"));
    }

    public void onDestroy()  {
        this.nm.cancelAll();
        stopForeground(true);
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent paramIntent, int paramInt1, int paramInt2)  {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(0);
            notif(titleNotif, contentNotif);
            return super.onStartCommand(paramIntent, paramInt1, paramInt2);
        } catch (InterruptedException localInterruptedException) {
            for (;;) {
                localInterruptedException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void notif(String titleNotif, String contentNotif){
        //building the notification
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.spy)
            .setContentTitle(titleNotif)
            .setTicker(contentNotif);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(ctx, MediaService.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, 
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        Notification n = mBuilder.build();
        nm.notify(1, n);
        // startForeground(12345, mBuilder.build());
    }

    public static void doRepeatTask(){
        t = new Timer();
        repeatTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                new Task().execute();
            }
        };
        t.schedule(repeatTask, 300, 3000); 
    }

    public static void stopRepeatTask(){
        if(repeatTask!=null){
            repeatTask.cancel();
            Log.d("TIMER", "timer canceled");
        }
        MainActivity.titleMusic.setText("");
        MainActivity.titleMusic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public static class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(soursetrack);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
                filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/cashe.xml";
                file = new File (filePath);
                CreateFileFromInputStream(in,  filePath) ;
                // Parse it with document builder factory
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder dBuilder = null;
                dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = null;
                doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                // The root element is 
                doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName();
                NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Name");

                for ( int i = 0 ; i < nList.getLength() ; i++ ) {
                    Element element = (Element) nList.item(i) ;
                    dataPlaying = getCharacterDataFromElement(element);
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (dataPlaying.equals(MainActivity.currentlyPlaying)){
                if (MainActivity.replay == true){
                    MainActivity.replay = false;
                    MainActivity.titleMusic.setText("" + MainActivity.currentlyPlaying); 
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("MainActivity","Change track");
                MainActivity.currentlyPlaying = dataPlaying;
                MainActivity.titleMusic.setText("" + MainActivity.currentlyPlaying);
                send();
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);  
        }
    }

    public static void send(){
        notif(MainActivity.currentlyPlaying,MainActivity.currentlyPlaying);
    }

    public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
        Node node = e.getFirstChild();
        if (node instanceof CharacterData) {
            CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) node;
            return cd.getData();
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static void CreateFileFromInputStream(InputStream inStream, String path)
            throws IOException {
        // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));

        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = inStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

        inStream.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

**LogCat:**

```
03-12 06:16:21.324: D/MediaService(3475): Change track
03-12 06:16:21.347: D/AndroidRuntime(3475): Shutting down VM
03-12 06:16:21.347: W/dalvikvm(3475): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
03-12 06:16:21.394: E/AndroidRuntime(3475): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 06:16:21.394: E/AndroidRuntime(3475): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 06:16:21.394: E/AndroidRuntime(3475):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
03-12 06:16:21.394: E/AndroidRuntime(3475):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3122)
03-12 06:16:21.394: E/AndroidRuntime(3475):     at com.spynetstation.MediaService.notif(MediaService.java:162)
03-12 06:16:21.394: E/AndroidRuntime(3475):     at com.spynetstation.MediaService.send(MediaService.java:250)
03-12 06:16:21.394: E/AndroidRuntime(3475):     at com.spynetstation.MediaService$Task.onPostExecute(MediaService.java:241)
03-12 06:16:21.394: E/AndroidRuntime(3475):     at com.spynetstation.MediaService$Task.onPostExecute(MediaService.java:1)
03-12 06:16:21.394: E/AndroidRuntime(3475):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
03-12 06:16:21.394: E/AndroidRuntime(3475):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
03-12 06:16:21.394: E/AndroidRuntime(3475):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
03-12 06:16:21.394: E/AndroidRuntime(3475):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-12 06:16:21.394: E/AndroidRuntime(3475):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 06:16:21.394: E/AndroidRuntime(3475):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-12 06:16:21.394: E/AndroidRuntime(3475):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 06:16:21.394: E/AndroidRuntime(3475):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-12 06:16:21.394: E/AndroidRuntime(3475):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-12 06:16:21.394: E/AndroidRuntime(3475):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-12 06:16:21.394: E/AndroidRuntime(3475):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: due to there is no value in currentlyPlaying.it's null. check it once using log.

Comment: currentlyPlaying not null without sending notice the title track appears normal

Comment: also create Notification Manager like:  `NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);`

Comment: In the onCreate() method, try using this.ctx = getApplicationContext();

Comment: Thanks but did not help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its the `context`.

Instead of `ctx=this`,

You can use `getApplicationContext()` or `getBaseContext()` inside your service to get the context.

Try using

```
ctx= getApplicationContext();
```

OR

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
```

Refer:
[android start activity from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service)

Comment: did you try clean build, are you sure its the same error, doesn't seem much in that line

Comment: I removed the code to handle the current track and dispatch of the notice of mainactivity and placed him in mediaservice but the same error and tighter line

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
```

With

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
```

Or

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
```

Comment: if I use ctx=getBaseContext(); the error is the same as if the Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class); is to change only writes "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getBaseContext() from the type ContextWrapper"

Comment: Try to use Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

Answer (score 0):

Because, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag is not support this.
So you can try getApplicationContext() or getBaseContext() instead ctx.
You can read this. It can be help you.
[android start activity from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service)

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a null context variable in ctx.  Also, your architecture is just wierd-  notif should not be a static member on the service.  It should be a non-static normal member function.  You should never have a static reference to a Context anywhere-  iots a leak.  And its not needed since a service is a context, it should be able to pass in this if notif wasn't static.  Anytime you find yourself putting multiple static variables in a class like that it's a sign that you've designed things wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use:-

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
```

Comment: if I use ctx=getApplicationContext(); the error is the same as if the Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext, MainActivity.class); is to change only writes "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getApplicationContext() from the type ContextWrapper"

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a null context variable in ctx.
well i have solution and it works well you have to create a static context in your main class and then use that context

```
public class LauncherActivityname extends ..... {

public static Context context;
.
.
.
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context=this
}
}
```

use this context insted of yout ctx and use it like

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(LauncherActivityname.context, MainActivity.class);
```