# Start Activity and Bring it to Front

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-activity, flags

I have a service that once it completes a task it launches an intent to start an activity from my application. Like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyService.this, MyActivityToBringToFront.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
//i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

This service can be running even after my application has been closed. When this is the case and my application is closed I need it to bring the activity to the front of whatever the user is currently doing. So if the user is in a different app I need my activity to pop up in front. Is this possible. None of the flags had any effect. Basically I need it to be like the system phone application. When you get a phone call it always brings the phone to the front. How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to keep context in memory to make intent's.

Secondary you need a mechanism that can re-obtaining your context every 24 hours because usually context stay alive in 24 hours.

After.

Launching Activity from service :

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), myActivity.class);
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3607934/2956344

To push activity on top add

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");

i.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.example.package/com.example.package.activityName"));

startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I used this and it does the same thing as my other code. It will start the activity I want but it will always be in the background. So if I am currently using the google play app for example once my service finishes it will put my activity behind google play. So I will not know until I exit out of google play that the service has finished... Any other ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyService.this, MyActivityToBringToFront.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
context.startActivity( i);
```

And API reference is

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the
>   current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that
>   activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and
>   this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a
>   new Intent.
>
> For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D.
>   If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the
>   component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive
>   the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.
>
> The currently running instance of activity B in the above example will
>   either receive the new intent you are starting here in its
>   onNewIntent() method, or be itself finished and restarted with the new
>   intent. If it has declared its launch mode to be "multiple" (the
>   default) and you have not set FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP in the same
>   intent, then it will be finished and re-created; for all other launch
>   modes or if FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is set then this Intent will be
>   delivered to the current instance's onNewIntent().
>
> This launch mode can also be used to good effect in conjunction with
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK: if used to start the root activity of a task,
>   it will bring any currently running instance of that task to the
>   foreground, and then clear it to its root state. This is especially
>   useful, for example, when launching an activity from the notification
>   manager.

Answer (score 0):

launching an activity from a service isn't always a good idea.  You may want to use notification for that. If the user clicks on the notification, thats the time you show the Activity.