# How to start activity from intentservice?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I have Service implements IntentService and in the OnHandleIntent I want to start activity.

It does not work:

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity1));
dialogIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
this.StartActivity(dialogIntent);
```

what else can I try?

upd: AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask); it doesnt help

Comment: Did you find the soln to your question? If yes,then pls share.Also have a  look at : " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service "

Answer (score 9):

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

Comment: This code works. I wonder I used same except getApplicationContext() didn't work for me. If any one using application context please replace getBaseContext().