# How to update the activity from Service in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I am learning `Android`. I have made a simple `Activity` then in the `Activity` start the `Service` that do some high network operation now I want when high network load call complete then I want to update to my `Activity`.

Is it possible to update the `Activity` from the `Service` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use BroadcastRecievers http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: @Deacoy How can I apply `BroadCastReceiver` here ?

Comment: Sorry, easier is actualey  starting an intent to your activity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service

Comment: @Deacoy How can you share a bit code to explain how your approach work ?

Comment: In the link I sent there is quite a good example...

Comment: How can you be shure the activity is still there ?

Comment: @Deacoy My requirement is not to start the activity again from Service. I need to simply update the UI View of Activity

Comment: @Deacoy lets suppose it is there. if its not there then I need to handle this case also.

Comment: With the intent you can send data. Intent.putExtra(Whateveryouwant..)

Comment: @Deacoy yes but that will recreate my activity

Comment: I would look into using a ResultReceiver that you pass to the service via an intent.

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie How that works ? can you please share a bit code to explain your comment

Comment: Hello Willian, care to explain a little more about your requirements? Or share a little bit of code? Thanks.

Comment: Have you saw this: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html (make sure you continue reading the following pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is code taken and modified from a now depreciated library called [DataDroid](https://github.com/foxykeep/DataDroid) but it is relevant to what you are attempting to do.

```
private final class RequestReceiver extends ResultReceiver {

    RequestReceiver() {
        super(new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()));

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        /*
         * Depending on how you implement this either update activity from here
         * or instantiate it with an interface that your activity implements and 
         * call that here. 
         */
    }
}
```

Create service with somethinglike this:

```
RequestReceiver requestReceiver = new RequestReceiver();

Intent i = new Intent(mContext, Service);
i.putExtra(RequestService.INTENT_EXTRA_RECEIVER, requestReceiver);
mContext.startService(i);
```

You could also just use the previously mentioned library and modify it to fit your current use case or use one of the many other similar libraries available.