# Launch Activity from Service

Tags: android, background-foreground

Can’t we launch an activity from a service ? If so, will the service keep running in background in a separate thread and the launched activity in foreground as a separate thread ?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can’t we launch an activity from a service ?

You can call `startActivity()` on a `Service` or any other `Context`.

> If so, will the service keep running in background in a separate thread and the launched activity in foreground as a separate thread ?

In Java, objects do not run on threads. Methods run on threads. The fact that the activity was launched from a service does not affect this at all. Pretty much everything with both an `Activity` and a `Service` by default occurs on the main application thread, and that too does not change because the `Service` launched an `Activity`.

Comment: @SteveJobs: In Java, objects do not run on threads. Methods run on threads.

Comment: Thatz ok but I require launching activity as a separate thread, any other method ??