# Activity gets minimized when launching it from foreground service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two Activities in my app:

A - login Activity

B - main Activity

When the user clicks the login button in activity A I am starting a service. In the service's onCreate() method I launch activity B like this:

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat
            .Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setContentTitle("Activity B in foreground service");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    startForeground(1, builder.build());
```

The problem is that Activity B launches minimized. I have to press the service button in the notification bar in order to get my activity maximized (fill the screen). How could I launch Activity B from service in normal way - without minimizing it (putting to background)?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't actually launch Activity B at all. All it does is create a `Notification`, that, if selected by the user, will launch Activity B.

If you want to actually launch Activity B, do this:

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    // Now launch the activity immediately
    startActivity(notificationIntent);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat
        .Builder(getApplicationContext());
    ... (rest of your code here)
```

Comment: Your solution works but when I press on service Notifcation later - Activity B reloads to initial state. For example, if I open fragment in Activity B and press service Notifcation button - Activity B reloads without opened fragment. This behaviour I didn't noticed in my initial code sample. Maybe there is a way to open service Notification programmatically?

Comment: You can fix that by adding `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` to `notificationIntent` or by declaring Activity B with `launchMode="singleTop"` in the manifest. This will prevent Android from creating a new instance of Activity B if there is already an instance of Activity B on the top of the activity stack in your task.

Answer (score 0):

Question already answered in [android start activity from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service)

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out the solution:

onCreate() method in service class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    getApplication().startActivity(notificationIntent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat
            .Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setContentTitle("Activity B runs in a foreground service");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    startForeground(1, builder.build());

}
```

In AndroidManifest.xml add this line in Activity element:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```