# How to start Fragment from IntentService class?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intentservice

I have a `Service` which is executed once in every 5 minute.It shows an `AlertDialog` when executed.I want to start a `Fragment` on `AlertDialog` button click.I tried to start the `Fragment` like

```
android.app.FragmentManager fm = ((Activity) getApplicationContext()).getFragmentManager();
```

but gives exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity`.

This is my code for `AlertDialog`:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext(),R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert)
                                .create();

                             // Setting Dialog Title
                                alertDialog.setTitle(eventNameEnglish);

                                // Setting Dialog Message

                                alertDialog.setMessage(eventAddressEnglish+"\n"+duration);


                        // Setting  View Details Button
                        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"View Details", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                android.app.FragmentManager fm = ((Activity) getApplicationContext()).getFragmentManager();

                                dialog_fragment = new DetailFragment("Events",
                                        eventNameEnglish, eventAddressEnglish,
                                        eventContactNumberEnglish, eventEmailEnglish, eventFaxEnglish,
                                        duration,eventOrganizerNameEnglish,
                                        eventDescriptionEnglish,eventFullDescriptionEnglish,
                                        eventLocationEnglish,eventImageEnglish,
                                        eventWebsiteEnglish
                                        );

                                dialog_fragment.show(fm, "detailScreen");
                            }
                        });

                        // Setting Cancel Button
                                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,"Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });

                        // Showing Alert Message
                        alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
                        alertDialog.show();
                            }
                        });
```

How to do this?Please help.

Comment: Please mention the reason before downvoting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception tells the problem. getApplicationContext return value cannot cast to Activity. You have to taget an existing activity.

I think you need some communication between the service and the activity.

You can use Eventbus or broadcastreceiver or something like that.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: So i can't start Fragment directly from Service?

Comment: You can start activity from service: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service

Comment: The link you provided is for starting Activity from Service not Fragment

Comment: You can "put" the Fragment on the Activity. If the Activity instance already exists you can send a broadcast event to do something with the fragment on the Activity. If the activity instance not exist, you have to start it.

Comment: I used BroadCastReceiver and it is working.Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Suppose i have two AlertDialogs waiting to be displayed.When i clicked on View details of first dialog,the detail fragment pops up but the second alert dialog comes on top of that dialog.Do you have any idea how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot show a `Fragment` alone, A `Fragment` can only display UI embedded within an `Activity`. So, you question is a bit to broad to be answered properly.

However, here are a couple of pointers:

1. write a, `activity_layout` with a `frame_layout` as placeholder for your fragment
2. write an `Activity` with `activity_layout` as content
3. register the activity in your AndroidManifest.xml
4. call startActivity on your service with a proper `Intent`
5. in the `onCreate` method of your `Activity`, you can get a `FragmentManager` and then show your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

you can start activity , then only you can show the fragment from that. This is because without activity , getFragmentManager() will return null