# Activity does not start when app is in background

Tags: android

When application is not in foreground and `startActivity` is called, app does not show up with new activity. This only happens on low end devices.
What can I do to make sure that the activity is started?

part of **Manifest** for second activity

```
<activity
     android:name=".OfferActivity"
     android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
     android:label="@string/title_activity_offer"
     android:launchMode="singleTop"
     android:noHistory="true"
     android:showOnLockScreen="true"/>
```

Comment: Hi share manifest.xml

Comment: Remove `android:launchMode="singleTop"` and try

Comment: Could you please add in your manifest for activity this :         <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

Comment: You say this happens on low end devices? Chances are the Activity has been destroyed to free system resources? Can you replicate the issue and put some life cycle logging in to see if this is happening

Comment: refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service

Comment: @MarkKeen The activity is alive, I log event before I call `startActivity()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the activity like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);  
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I does not help

Comment: Can you show any logcat to help us? With the information provided is practically impossible.....