# Android getContext on a background Service

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-context

I'm trying to create a *Service* that runs even when my app is closed. However, I need to use my app *Context* inside this *Service*. When the app is running, the service works as well, but when I close the app (onDestroy() was called), the `getContext()` always returns `null`.

**Service**

```
public class SubscribeService extends Service {

    private Context context;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = this; //Returns null when service is running on background
        context = MyApp.getContext(); //Also null
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //do stuff using context
    }
```

**MyApp**

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    public static Context getContext() {
        return context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        context = getApplicationContext();
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

**Service start from Activity onCreate()**

```
startService(new Intent(this, SubscribeService.class));
```

How should I use the *Context* in this scenario?

**Edit**

Managed to get it to work properly after **Onik**'s help.
I just had to call the `MyApp.getContext();` before `super.onCreate();`
Like so:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    context = MyApp.getContext();
    super.onCreate();
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service) extends [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context). You can use `this`, where `this` is the reference to the `Service` instance.

Putting more details on my comment below regarding the following code of *SubscribeService* class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = this;
    context = MyApp.getContext();
}
```

In your `Service`'s `onCreate()` `context = this` cannot be `null` by a fundamental programming paradigm.

Comment: Managed to get it to work after your help, however, using `this` was not enough, I had to use `context = MyApp.getContext();` before `super.onCreate();`

Answer (score 4):

**Try this:**

Added `super.onCreate();` before `MyApp.context = getApplicationContext();`

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MyApp.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyApp.context;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Calling `MyApp.getAppContext()` will return the application `Context`.

Comment: Yes, that was it!
Thank you as well, I think I need to read a little more about the `super` call.

Answer (score 1):

already once left an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42189308/549372), which was to use `getApplicationContext()` in the `Service`.

also, using an [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService) with `Context.startService(Intent)` might make sense here.

... and do not insert statements before calling to `super.onCreate()`.