# Starting activity from a service

Tags: java, android, service

I have a background service and two activities in my app.
First i start A activity and this activity is starting a service.
Then i use home button so A activity is moved to background.
Next service is starting B activity, this activity is transparent.

Problem is that when B activity starts, it brings A activity to front.
How to overcome this behaviour.

Comment: "Next service is starting B activity, this activity is transparent" -- that is banned on Android Q. You cannot start an activity from the background. Please switch to using notifications.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service you cant do this going forward tho